# Why is the use of @variable in this SQL statement not yielding results?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

Hopefully a simple one, probably something silly that I've missed.
Why is the following statement not yielding any results:

```
SET @old_sites_path = 'sites/mysite.co.uk/', @sites_path = 'sites/default/'

-- Update the content within blocks
UPDATE `boxes`
SET `body` = REPLACE(`body`, @old_sites_path+'files', @sites_path+'files');
```

However if I simply substitute the variables in I get the result?

```
-- Update the content within blocks
UPDATE `boxes`
SET `body` = REPLACE(`body`, 'sites/mysite.co.uk/files', 'sites/default/files');
```

Just for background this is part of a larger script that helps me manage the deployment of Drupal databases.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this to get a clue:

```
SELECT 'sites/mysite.co.uk/' + 'files'
```

Then have a look at [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Comment: Yeah, I just ran this `SELECT @old_sites_path+'files';` which returned 0, and then I remembered I was mixing MSSQL into my script. Naughty naughty. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Cryptic answer, but effective enough if the OP has the intelligence to work it out (which he does). (For those who don't get it: the '+' sign in MySQL is used to add numbers - the original poster needs to use the CONCAT function to concatenate strings.)